# How to Escape Characters in String in Firestore Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to check if an incoming string is an email, so I wrote the following Firestore Security Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /signups/{uid} {
            // RegExp copied from https://www.regextester.com/19
            allow create: if newData().email.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I deploy it using `firebase deploy --only firestore`:

```
=== Deploying to '[my-project-id]'...

i  deploying firestore
i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
i  firestore: reading indexes from firestore.indexes.json...

Error: Compilation errors in firestore.rules:
[E] 5:139 - Unexpected '['.
[E] 5:149 - Unexpected ']'.
[E] 5:151 - token recognition error at: '?'
[E] 5:171 - Unexpected '['.
[E] 5:183 - token recognition error at: '?'
[E] 8:1 - Unexpected '}'.
```

Here is the screenshot on the Firebase Console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWoNt.jpg

Apparently, the RegExp string ends at the `'` character (5:73). How can I escape the string in Firestore Rules? I cannot find any documentation on this problem.

Comment: The API documentation you're looking for is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches).  It gives you a link to the definition of the regex syntax.

Comment: Hmm... Does my regex violate the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I found out that `'` is not ending the string. The problem is the not-escaped `\` before `.`. I replaced `\` with `\\` and the rules compiled successfully.

```
allow create: if newData().email.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$");
```